# Program needing elevation in Startup registry key (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, uac, startup, elevation

I have a program that I'd to run when the computer starts. I've put its path inside "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run". This is in Windows 7. When the computer starts nothing happens. I'm thinking this is because the program needs elevation when I run it. But Windows does not ask for permission to elevate and gives no feedback. It simply ignores it. I've read that Vista tells you that the program was blocked etc. Does anybody have any idea why Windows 7 simply ignores the application?

Thank you very much in advance.

Alireza

Comment: Because bugging the user with UAC alerts every time they turn on the computer is a bad idea.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the program?

Comment: Just a thought... but I had a similar problem because the path to my executable had slashes (/) instead of backslashes (\). I know it's dumb, but I had that issue.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Vista and 7 block programs requiring elevation from startup to prevent a flurry of UAC prompts at each startup.    [This blog entry from the UAC team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uac/archive/2006/08/23/715265.aspx) explains it pretty clearly.   As a workaround, create a task scheduler entry to start the program if your program absolutely must run with elevated privileges.